# Exe that works always

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want to set my computer so an exe will always run and it will be never stopped. 
The exe has a critical flag, so when it's launched, it can't be stopped. 
I registered it in the run of the registry so it start automatically.

The question is is it still possible to someone to launch the computer without this exe running?

1.he can enter to safe mode and delete the entry of the registry, so how can i set the exe to automaticlly launch also in safe mode? 
2. He can enter to the computer with a linux installation, and delete the entry from the registry, and also delete the exe itself .

The question is how to protect that a maximum. I know that there wil be always someone who will find a trick i didn't think about it, but how can i protect this a maximum.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Full disk encryption will prevent both
- Securing physical access to computer case, having the .exe run with administrator permission, securing administrator account and adding a password to BIOS (obviously disabling booting from any other than local HDD and safe mode) should prevent both

Comment: It mostly works against general population, (and I completely agree with `Hex`) but not for all people according to M$ [Ten Immutable Laws Of Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh278941.aspx#EIAA)

Comment: Thx. I'm talking about a software wich is installing an application and try to protect it.